# Using MemoryCache.Default in Module causes Error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed error during build

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In an asp.net webform application project framework 4.7.2 with Option Infer On, including the line `Dim cache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default` in a method, causes the `Error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed` in several aspx files (no obvious reason for why those files and not others that I can see) when building on our build server.

I don't have any unincluded files (I had an unincluded AssemblyInfo.vb file, I deleted it, no difference).

It's taken me quite a while to narrow it down to this, and I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any solutions or suggestions welcome.